# Navigational Buttons not resetting to inactive state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a primary and secondary navigation, when the user clicks a link the background-image of this link will change to an "active" state and reset all other links to "inactive". This works fine for my primary navigation, but my secondary navigation is not resetting resulting in all of my links having an active state. My Code:
HTML

```
<nav id="menu">
<div id="container">
<a href="#" id="menu-link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="menu-link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="menu-link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="menu-link4">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" id="menu-link5">Link 5</a>
<a href="#" id="menu-link6">Link 6</a>
</div>
</nav><!--END MENU-->

<div id="upperContent-title">Welcome</div>
<div id="upperContent-body">
Welcome Text
</div>
<img id="upperContent-img" src="img/welcomeImg.png"/>
</div><!--END UPPER CONTENT-->

<nav id="middleNav">
<div id="middleContainer">
<a href="#" id="middleNavLinkCorner-link7">Link 7</a>
<a href="#" id="middleNavLink-link8">Link 8</a>
</div>
</nav><!--END MIDDLE NAV-->
```

CSS:

```
#menu{
    background-image:url(../menuBottom.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:4px;
    width:1024px;
    height:25px;
    }
#container{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:-3px;
    height:24px;
    }
nav a[id*="menu"]{
    background-image:url(../mainNav.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial,san-sarif;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:-4px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:129px;
    height:25px;
    }
#upperContent{
    background-image:url(../upperWelcome.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1024px;
    height:306px;

    }
#upperContent-title{
    margin-left:60px;
    padding-top:40px;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:36px;
    color:#00853f;
    width:459px;
    }
#upperContent-body{
    margin-left:60px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    width:459px;
    }
#upperContent-img{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:578px;
    margin-top:-183px;
    }
#middleNav{
    background-image:url(../middleNavBG.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1024px;
    height:43px;
    }
#middleContainer{
    margin-left:57px;
    }
nav a[id*="middleNav"]{
    background-image:url(../middleNavRect.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial,san-sarif;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:-4px;
    padding-top:8px;
    margin-top:3px;
    width:116px;
    height:37px;
    }
nav a[id*="middleNavCorner"]{
    background-image:url(../middleNavRound.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial,san-sarif;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:-4px;
    padding-top:8px;
    margin-top:3px;
    width:116px;
    height:37px;
    }
```

JS:

```
//Initialize Document.ready
$(function(){
        //Navigation

            //Main Nav
            $("a[id*='menu']").on({
                click:function(e){
                        $("nav a[id*='menu']").css('background-image','url(urlHere/mainNav.png)');
                        $(this).css('background-image','url(urlHere/mainNavVisit.png)');
                    }
                });
            //Secondary Nav
            $("a[id*='middleNav']").on({
                click:function(e){
                        $("nav a[id*='middleNavLink']").css('background-image','url(urlHere/middleNavRect.jpg');
                        $(this).css('background-image','url(urlHere/middleNavRectVisit.jpg)');
                    }
            });
});//End Document.ready
```

JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle Of Intended Result](https://jsfiddle.net/hexobolic/tczcqsub/3/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: OK so if the secondary nav is setting the links to active, you know the click event is definitely firing. Which could suggest there is a problem with your line of code selecting all the nav a's to reset them. I'd try something like: $("nav a[id*='middleNavLink']").addClass("testing"); and then check them in dev tools, just to make sure they're getting picked up by your selection. If they are, it suggests perhaps a problem with the .css part of the code - perhaps an incorrect image url? I note the first nav code has .png, but the second lot has .jpg - should it also be .png? Long shot, but...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Luke, it appears to have been fixed now, but I appreciate taking the time to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been within my .js document. I copied over the working code from my primary nav and used it for my secondary nav and it appears to work fine, trying to isolate the exact cause of the initial issue, but it appears to have been some sort of targeting or misspelling. thanks.